# how to forward IP request to a specific port

Tags: domain-name-system, iptables, bind

I have 2 servers

- the first (SRV01) is running Bind and other web app
- the second (SRV02) is running 2 server Minecraft (^^)

in Bind I have 2 A recording for the 2 server MC

```
s1.domain.tld    A    SRV02IP
s2.domain.tld    A    SRV02IP
```

the 2 MC serv are running on 2 different port 25565 and 25566

so I want that the request from `s1.domain.tld:25565` are going to `SRV02IP:25565`
and the request from `s2.domain.tld:25565` are going to `SRV02IP:25566`

I think I need do this in the SRV02 iptables. I have looking some topic about iptables but nothing pertinent to me.

could you help me ?

rgds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as both servers are publicly accessible, this is possible.
Point s1.domain.tld to SRV01IP and point s2.domain.tld to SRV02IP.
s2.domain.tld:25565 already works. Setup minecraft on :25566 on SRV02IP, and then in iptables on SRV01IP you need to forward :25565 to SRV02IP:25566:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 25565 -j DNAT --to-destination SRV02IP:25566
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 25566 -j MASQUERADE
```

Finally, to make it work you'll need to enable IP forwarding in proc:

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

All set. One thing to note is that this won't persist between reboots. To make it persist make sure you save your IPTables rules (differs depending on distro) and edit /etc/sysctl.conf to make the ip_forward persist by editing the following line (or adding it if it doesn't exist):

> net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

Comment: yes the 2 server are publicly accessible   s1.domain.tld need to point to SRV02IP:25565 and s2.domain2.tld point to SRV02IP:25566

Comment: ok no problem I have miss read

Comment: I can't add your iptables rules, i see nothing with iptables --list

Comment: You won't because iptables --list doesn't show the nat table by default. Try iptables -t nat --list

Comment: I have a trouble, now, with some similar, I have try this : iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d ts.domain.tld --dport 9987 -j DNAT --to-destination domainIP:9988, but ts.domain.tld is replace bay the kimsufi hostname in the iptable list

Comment: but I have 3 other domain on this server

Comment: and i'm not rerouting to the port 9988

Comment: Don't use hostnames, use IP addresses. If you have three domains on that server but only one IP, as far as IPTables is concerned you only have one "domain". If you can't redirect :25565 for that IP you can't use this method. I'm not sure what -d ts.domain.tld is supposed to be - try just copying my rules as they are and replacing ports and IP addresses only.

Comment: your rules work fine, but I have modified it to do something strange ^^, it's on the same server, I want to redirect the request going on ts.domain1.tld:9987 on port 9988, but on this same server there was an other domain/sub (ts.domain2.tld) using the port 9987

Comment: if ts.domain2.tld points to the same IP address as ts.domain1.tld, it won't work.

Comment: I have seen that ^^

Comment: no more solution ?

Answer (score 2):

Just bind another IP to SRV02. If you don't have extra external IP's can also use internals (with some extra tricks). Install Squid proxy. That can redirect the traffic to another port.

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/debian-iptables-squid-redirect-port-80-to-port-8080-on-another-machine-474027/

Comment: A reverse proxy would do. If not squid fits your need, you could probably do it with apache.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have one public IP and two back-end servers with private IPs (?) - If this is the case what you are asking is impossible: You cannot have two applications listening on the same port and (public) IP address.

You cannot do this from DNS (DNS `A` records have no concept of "port"), and doing it from iptables is the Wrong Thing (it may not even be possible, but if it were it would involve doing DNS lookups in a firewall rule which is not something I would advise).
You need two public IP addresses to make this work, or you need to run one of your Minecraft servers on an alternate port.

Comment: IPTables can do hostname lookups but it only resolves them when the rules are loaded. It's not recommended. I think IP is fine in this instance though.

Comment: @JamesLawrie Can != Should -- No matter where it's done I'm 1000% against making IP-level configuration (firewalls) depend on the ability to resolve hostnames (DNS)...

Comment: See my "it's not recommended" in the above comment. My comment was only in response to "it may not even be possible", which it is. I've given OP a solution which doesn't depend on hostname lookups.